# How to set up exchange to hold email through a certain account until verified

Tags: email, exchange

I am looking to set up an exchange server within the office, but there are certain colleagues within the sales staff that would require an account, but are not fully trusted until they have been at the business for more than a certain amount of time.

is there a way that i can have all emails sent by their accounts to be held at the server until somebody manually verifies that particular email and allows it to continue on to its intended destination.

Is this even possible with exchange? If not, how would i go about setting this up at all?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of Exchange?  DLP (either built in or 3rd party) might be able to get you what you want (since it seems the requirement is outbound).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would use a Hub Transport Rule and set the condition to "sent from people" (choose the users), and the action to "forward message to addresses for moderation".  The messages sent from those users in the condition, will be sent to the address(es) selected for moderation and will need to be approved before being sent.

This is if you are using Exchange 2010 or Exchange 2013.